# Short story: Modem improves user's BBS or Usenet posts, ultimately kills him

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, sentience

Short story plot: Narrator notices that the quality of a friend's BBS or Usenet posts has improved -- just expanded diction and perfect spelling, at first, I think. He finds out his friend has been using some unknown-brand modem (I think it was mentioned as having an unsettling red indicator LED), which seems to be improving his posts automatically. Evidence of self-aware AI mounts, and after some panicked last communication from the owner to the narrator, it appeared to have killed the owner -- I think maybe by triggering an electrical fire -- but that couldn't be proven.

(<s>I have some recollection of a device killing it's owner by using a [basilisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Langford#Basilisks)/Snowcrash-like image to transmit a mind virus that causes the owner to kill himself by sticking his head in a microwave oven with a defeated safety interlock, but I think that element was from some other story.</s> *This element is indeed from a different story, "Press Enter ■" [ID](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152225/story-identification-old-man-has-hacker-neighbor-who-mysteriously-dies)ed in the comment by JAB, below.*)

This was probably in an Analog, Asimov's, or F&SF from the '80s, although it could have also been elsewhere and appeared in some collection.

Comment: The mind virus one is probably https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152225/story-identification-old-man-has-hacker-neighbor-who-mysteriously-dies

Comment: This sounds fun!

Comment: @JAB Yeah, that's definitely the other story I picked up the microwave detail from, thanks.

Comment: I hate when that happens.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be "[Pickman's Modem](http://www.watt-evans.com/PickmansModem.shtml)" ([ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42122)) by Lawrence Watt-Evans. It was indeed published in Asimov's (though 1992, not 80s).

A decent summary can be found [here](http://www.soullessmachine.com/2007/07/pickmans-modem-by-lawrence-watt-evans.html):

> As the story progress and the narrator, George, has brief Internet encounters with Pickman, the story spirals into the wonderful Mythos pitfalls that ensnare a large number of characters. Pickman and George get together and investigate strange messages. Pickman’s postings and emails are being rewritten after they are sent and before they reach the intended reader.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I embedded the ISFDB link and added one to Lawrence Watt-Evans's site's entry.

Comment: Found a copy online; indeed this is it, thank you. The summary you linked perhaps exaggerates a bit — it doesn't really *ensnare* a large number of characters, other than escalating a flame war with some unnamed correspondents with florid insults. I had forgotten (having perhaps not understood at the time) the Cthulhu mythos references, e.g. "it was an oblong of black plastic, featureless save for the two red lights that shone balefully from the front and the small metal plate bolted to one side where incised letters spelled out 'Miskatonic Data Systems, Arkham MA, Serial #R1LYEH'". Tag added.

Comment: And the tag has now been removed. @TheLethalCarrot I put it in for the reason stated above. Someone else may remember it as a Cthulhu mythos story and search for it on that basis. Why did you remove the tag?