# Short story around 1960 about a dangerous AI system, with a number of strange suicides connected in some way

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

The main character realises there is something dangerous about an AI system, with a number of strange suicides connected in some way. He attempts to investigate cautiously and gets help from a woman yet she also commits suicide in a very strange way. I believe it was written a very long time ago and yet foresaw the danger from AI.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the the [tour].

Comment: *"Foresaw"*  foresaw what danger from AI? are you suggesting there is a real extant and present danger from AI that has actually come to pass? as apposed to hysterical 'what if' fantasies from the largely ignorant (like my mum, hasn't a clue, actually bought into the whole mid 80s DnD is devil worship thing) and media hacks or shock jocks trying to sell tabloid stories or generate clicks, would be news to me.

Comment: Since you accepted in a comment, and we do have an accepted answer for this, I have closed as a duplicate. You will still get up upvotes for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"[Press Enter ■](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41040)" by John Varley as per the answer to [Story identification: Old man has hacker neighbor who mysteriously dies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/152225/23243)

It starts with the narrator being called to the house of his neighbor, who has apparently killed himself in front of his computer. Later on, the woman helping him, a Vietnamese hacker noted to have large breasts, is found having killed herself using her microwave. He eventually realizes that all of these deaths are caused by a malignant force that can travel through electrical wires, and is already in the phone and online systems and the story ends with him trying to be as much off the grid as possible.

One non-matching aspect is that it was written in the '80s.

Comment: Yes that's it thanks ! I clearly was out with the year but did think it was good prediction.